# How can I publish the asset from resources directory to public directory in laravel 9 and vite

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vite, laravel-9

I don't know, how can I publish the assets from resources directory to the public directory in Laravel 9 and Vite.

I try this but it's not working.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
            'resources/css/global/plugins.css',
            'resources/css/style.css',
            {
                from: 'resources/assets',
                to: 'public/assets',
            }
        ]),
    ],
});
```

Comment: You can use something like : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy to copy your folder, or you can set your publicDir to resources/assets in vite config, this will copy resources/assets to public, so without the assets subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                //the remaining code
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

then run

```
npm run build
```

a folder with your compiled assets will be created